# If StartMenuInternet is not set, where else can I look for the default browser?

Tags: c#, windows, regedit

```
key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet", false);
if (key == null)
{
    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet", false);
}
```

On a very few machines this is coming up blank.  When regedit is probed, the key is found to be (value not found).  What are my options?

Comment: Are you trying to do something more than just launch the default browser?

Comment: Then see Michael's answer; starting a URL specifying a protocol (HTTP: in this case) will cause the default browser to launch. This is true of other protocols as (and fake protocols such as email:).

Comment: Oh ok. This was my suspicion. Then see Michael's answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed

```
if (key == null || key.ValueCount == 0)
                {
                    key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet", false);
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want to launch a website in the default browser:

```
string url = "http://server.com";
Process.Start(url);
```

will do it.